# What changes are being made to VIRGO and LIGO (if any)?

Tags: gravitational-waves

Gravitational wave detectors [VIRGO and LIGO](https://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/201710/virgo.cfm) are currently down for some updates, slated to be completed sometime early next year (they hope). What exactly are they doing? I hadn't heard it was down again after the last set of updates awhile ago. What are they updating now-- is that knowledge public domain?

**Source:** I went to an astronomy club meeting and it was stated in the presentation.

Comment: https://www.ligo.org/scientists/GWEMalerts.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, LIGO and Virgo are in what's known as a [commissioning phase](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/news/ligo20180921), a scheduled stage where the teams work on improving the sensitivity of the detectors. A big part of this is noise reduction, but there are other technical updates ([an evolving plan](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0670) also mentions increasing the power of the lasers and adding a "squeezed vacuum source"). Virgo in particular is [replacing the steel fibers that hold up their mirrors with silica ones](https://cplberry.com/2018/06/16/1304-0670-2-the-explosioning/). The original silica fibers failed and were replaced with steel ones before last year's detection of GW170817, but now new silica ones are being added.

As of October, [the Livingston site has reached low noise levels, while Hanford is still a bit away](https://www.ligo.org/scientists/GWEMalerts.php). Virgo isn't quite there yet. Soon, though, the three detectors should begin a couple of joint [engineering runs](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/news/ligo20180921), testing the hardware updates before O3 (the third, year-long, observing session) begins in February.